# Simplifying a complex term

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I simplify this term $\frac{7+5i}{i-1}$? I've tried multiplying both numerator and denominator with $-1-i$, but in results in a division by zero.

Comment: Impossible: multiplying a complex number by its conjugate results in the square of its module.

Comment: My mistake. I overlooked that $i^2=-1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{7+5i}{i-1}=\frac{(7+5i)(i+1)}{(i-1)(i+1)}=\frac{(7+5i)(i+1)}{-2}=\frac{2+12i}{-2}=-1-6i$$